# Is there a way to remove the "/json/reply/" section of the url?

Tags: servicestack-bsd

I would like the URL for a request to be `/AmazingRequest` (or even `/AmazingService`) instead of `/json/reply/AmazingRequest`.

I've tried the `Route` attribute, but it seems to have no effect. Is it possible within ServiceStack, or would I have to resort to URL rewriting?

This is what I've tried. It compiles, but the attribute has no effect.

```
public class MyServiceEndpoints : IService
{
    [Route("/AmazingService")]
    public AmazingResponse Post(AmazingRequest request)
    {
        return new Amazing(request).GetResponse();
    }
}
```

I realize I would need to tell ServiceStack that it is a json request, but I'm fine with adding the `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers or maybe even a `?format=json` to the query string.

P.S. I'm using the BSD version of ServiceStack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ServiceStack Routes are defined on the Request DTO as it's part of your Service Contract, e.g:

```
[Route("/AmazingService")]
public class AmazingRequest { ... }
```

The [pre-defined Route](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing#pre-defined-routes) you're using is because ServiceStack doesn't think there's any custom route defined for your Service and just uses the default one.

The alternative way for declaring your Routes is to use the [Fluent Registration API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing#fluent-api) in your AppHost, e.g:

```
public void Configure(Container container)
{
    Routes
      .Add<AmazingRequest>("/AmazingService");
}
```

But the benefit of defining them on the Request DTO's is that your .NET Service Clients will also have access to them and will be able to use your custom routes instead of falling back to the pre-defined routes.

Comment: What if I want to use the request name (`public object Post(Hello request`) as the path, and base path is "/", so it doesnt become `/json/reply/Hello`, but instead `/Hello`. Id like to avoid using the Route attribute, as it seems bloated if I just want the methods available as defined in the service classes. So, with `Hello`, `Goodbye` and `SomeOtherMethod` available in the webservice, Id like them to simple have the path `/Hello, /Goodbye, /SomeOtherMethod` and not be forced to specify it in a string attribute in each service class.

Comment: @Ted Please ask new questions in a new question. You can't override the pre-defined routes, see [Auto Route Generation Strategies](https://docs.servicestack.net/routing#auto-route-generation-strategies) for ways to auto generate routes.